# Sample server to support 100-continue

Tags: http, http-headers, netty

I started implementing a sample server (in netty) to support 100 continue.
I got some confusion when I go thrugh the [RCF2616](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2616.html) section 8.2.3. It says

> Upon receiving a request which includes an Expect request-header
>           field with the "100-continue" expectation, an origin server MUST
>           either respond with 100 (Continue) status and continue to read
>           from the input stream, or respond with a final status code. The
>           origin server MUST NOT wait for the request body before sending
>           the 100 (Continue) response. If it responds with a final status
>           code, it MAY close the transport connection or it MAY continue
>           to read and discard the rest of the request.  It MUST NOT
>           perform the requested method if it returns a final status code.

What does it mean by *The origin server MUST NOT wait for the request body before sending the 100 (Continue) response.* 
Should my server first validate the headers and then send the 100 (continue) status code or Immediately send the 100 status code ?

Please clarify me the actual behavior of a http server to support 100 continue

Currently this is my `channelRead`

```
@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
    if (msg instanceof HttpRequest) {
        HttpRequest req = (HttpRequest) msg;

        request = req;
        if (req.getMethod() != HttpMethod.POST) {
            FullHttpResponse response = new DefaultFullHttpResponse(HTTP_1_1, METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED);
            ctx.write(response).addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
        } else {

            boolean valid = false;
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> header : req.headers()) {
                if (header.getKey().equals("my-special-header")) {
                    valid = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!valid) {
                FullHttpResponse resp = new DefaultFullHttpResponse(HTTP_1_1, BAD_REQUEST);
                ctx.write(resp).addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);

            } else {
                if (HttpHeaders.is100ContinueExpected(request)) {
                    ctx.write(new DefaultFullHttpResponse(HTTP_1_1, CONTINUE));
                }
            }

        }

    } else if (msg instanceof LastHttpContent && msg != LastHttpContent.EMPTY_LAST_CONTENT) {
        DefaultLastHttpContent content = (DefaultLastHttpContent) msg;

        System.out.println("content read");
        FullHttpResponse response = new DefaultFullHttpResponse(HTTP_1_1, OK, content.content());
        response.headers().set(CONTENT_TYPE, "text/plain");
        response.headers().set(CONTENT_LENGTH, response.content().readableBytes());

        boolean keepAlive =HttpHeaders.isKeepAlive(request);
        if (!keepAlive) {
            ctx.write(response).addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
        } else {
            response.headers().set(CONNECTION, Values.KEEP_ALIVE);
            ctx.write(response);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: RFC 2616 has been obsoleted. You may want to read <http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7231.html#header.expect> instead.

Comment: Thanks, but I am still unclear with `The origin server must not wait for the message body before sending the 100 (Continue) response.`
Currently my implementation check for the valid header and sends 100 or bad request

Answer (score 0):

I think "MUST NOT wait for the request body" is pretty clear. The body does not include thee headers, so I'm not sure where your confusion comes from...